# Can't launch Upsource on my dedicated server

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, jetbrains-ide, upsource

for my work, I would like use Upsource. But I can't launch app on my server.

Upsource start and load many services but when it's try load Upsource Frontend I've many errors and Upsource stop all services. On my local computer Upsource work with no problems.

```
upsource-frontend: [Upsource Frontend Error] Error initializing messaging server
[2016-08-27 18:28:01,936] upsource-frontend: Upsource Frontend failed to start
[2016-08-27 18:28:01,937] * Error while starting JetBrains Upsource 3.0: 
Not allowed exit code 255 from process: bin/upsource-frontend start 
[2016-08-27 18:28:01,947] * Stopping Upsource PSI 
[2016-08-27 18:28:04,625] upsource-psi: Upsource PSI Service is not running
[2016-08-27 18:28:04,626] * Stopping Upsource Frontend 
[2016-08-27 18:28:07,256] upsource-frontend: Upsource Frontend is not running
[2016-08-27 18:28:07,257] * Stopping Upsource Monitoring 
[2016-08-27 18:28:15,216] upsource-monitoring: Upsource Monitoring has shut down
[2016-08-27 18:28:15,227] * Stopping Upsource Analyzer 
[2016-08-27 18:28:21,026] upsource-analyzer: Upsource Analyzer has shut down
[2016-08-27 18:28:21,026] * Stopping Upsource Cluster Initialize Service 
[2016-08-27 18:28:23,632] upsource-cluster-init: Upsource Cluster Initialize Service is not running
[2016-08-27 18:28:23,642] * Stopping Apache Cassandra 
[2016-08-27 18:28:29,216] cassandra: Apache Cassandra has shut down
[2016-08-27 18:28:29,216] * Stopping Bundle Hub Configurator 
[2016-08-27 18:28:29,216] * Stopping Hub 
[2016-08-27 18:28:29,411] 18:28:29,407 WARN  [EventsMultiplexer             ] Can't access events multiplexer: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eventsMultiplexer': Bean creation not allowed while this factory is in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
[2016-08-27 18:28:29,412] 18:28:29,408 WARN  [EventsMultiplexer             ] Can't access events multiplexer: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eventsMultiplexer': Bean creation not allowed while this factory is in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
[2016-08-27 18:28:29,412] 18:28:29,408 WARN  [EventsMultiplexer             ] Can't access events multiplexer: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eventsMultiplexer': Bean creation not allowed while this factory is in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
[2016-08-27 18:28:29,423] 18:28:29,422 WARN  [EventsMultiplexer             ] Can't access events multiplexer: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'eventsMultiplexer': Bean creation not allowed while this factory is in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method impleenter code herementation!)
```

---

```
[Upsource Frontend Error] Failed to invoke "main" method of the class "com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter": null
[Upsource Frontend Error] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppWrapperBootstrap2.main2(AppWrapperBootstrap2.java:35)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.util.BootstrapUtil.doCallMain2(BootstrapUtil.java:51)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.util.BootstrapUtil.callMain2(BootstrapUtil.java:18)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppWrapperBootstrap.main(AppWrapperBootstrap.java:11)
[Upsource Frontend Error] Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.JLThread.start(JLThread.java:48)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.DiagnosticServiceImpl.(DiagnosticServiceImpl.java:15)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.BaseApplicationContext.(BaseApplicationContext.java:11)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter.(AppStarter.java:43)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter.(AppStarter.java:22)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter$1.run(AppStarter.java:33)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.Initializer.runWithContext(Initializer.java:34)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter.main(AppStarter.java:29)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     ... 13 more
Unexpected exit. Restarting. Run time was: 1.562 sec.
[Upsource Frontend Error] Failed to invoke "main" method of the class "com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter": null
[Upsource Frontend Error] java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppWrapperBootstrap2.main2(AppWrapperBootstrap2.java:35)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.util.BootstrapUtil.doCallMain2(BootstrapUtil.java:51)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.util.BootstrapUtil.callMain2(BootstrapUtil.java:18)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppWrapperBootstrap.main(AppWrapperBootstrap.java:11)
[Upsource Frontend Error] Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.JLThread.start(JLThread.java:48)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.DiagnosticServiceImpl.(DiagnosticServiceImpl.java:15)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.BaseApplicationContext.(BaseApplicationContext.java:11)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter.(AppStarter.java:43)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter.(AppStarter.java:22)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter$1.run(AppStarter.java:33)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.Initializer.runWithContext(Initializer.java:34)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.AppStarter.main(AppStarter.java:29)
[Upsource Frontend Error]     ... 13 more
Unexpected exit. Restarting. Run time was: 1.248 sec.
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.util.BootstrapUtil.doCallMain2(BootstrapUtil.java:51)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.util.BootstrapUtil.callMain2(BootstrapUtil.java:18)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:15)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.LauncherBootstrap.main(LauncherBootstrap.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:714)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.run.AgentStatusWatcherImpl.(AgentStatusWatcherImpl.java:22)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.run.AgentRunner.startWatchingAgentStatus(AgentRunner.java:61)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.run.AgentRunner.run(AgentRunner.java:23)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.commands.Run$1.run(Run.java:82)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.lock.AppLockFactory.withLock(AppLockFactory.java:19)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.commands.Run.doRun(Run.java:69)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.commands.BaseCommand.runCommand(BaseCommand.java:77)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.commands.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:61)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.Main$1.run(Main.java:26)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.Initializer.runWithContext(Initializer.java:16)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.Main.doMain(Main.java:20)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.Main.main(Main.java:16)
    at com.jetbrains.launcher.ep.LauncherBootstrap2.main2(LauncherBootstrap2.java:11)
    ... 8 more
Upsource Frontend failed to start
```

[upsource-stdout.log](https://gist.github.com/Selmac/c23fae4a27c495775de4dc3bd139805b)

[upsource-frontend/all.log](https://gist.github.com/Selmac/e5862dbec98f288b0734fa9d7e722d6c)

Can you help me?
Thanks

My server : 6 x86 64bit Cores, 8GB memory run on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow? Could you expand your question and add a summary of exceptions which you got? How did you try to solve the problem yourself? [Here are some general hints regarding asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you check how much free RAM is on the server? And how much RAM is available for JVM?

Comment: My server : 6 x86 64bit Cores, 8GB memory run on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I've test on my local, remove and re-install java, files and try on root...
I've send logs on gist because it's very big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you might have experience consequences of [a bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-6943) which hits systemd users of Ubuntu 16.04. The bug is related to the change of default values in configuration of [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) on Ubuntu.

According to another [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/percona-cluster/+bug/1578080), this bug should be fixed in [`systemd 229-6ubuntu1`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/229-6ubuntu1) which was released about two weeks ago, so you should probably try updating your system.

If, for some strange reason, you don't want to update your system, you can modify your systemd configuration using following settings:

```
[Service]
TasksMax=infinity
```

as it was suggested in [the first bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/UP-6943).